# how to roundup minute value?

Tags: java, android, time

In my android application i need to roundup tmie value.i.e

I need to convert,like

```
"05-Aug-2011 12:41 PM" into  "05-Aug-2011 12:40 PM".and
"05-Aug-2011 12:44 PM" into  "05-Aug-2011 12:45 PM".
```

i.e minutes has roundup.5 minute interval.

Pls give an example..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date rounded = new Date(Math.round((origDate.getTime() / (1000.0 * 60 * 5))) * (1000 * 60 * 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm aa");
try {
    System.out.println(sdf.format(
            Math.round(sdf.parse("05-Aug-2011 12:44 PM").getTime()/300000.0)*300000));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the time you get will be in Date or some format.. so say

```
Long l = date.getMinutes();
```

then use

```
    if(l/10<5){
if(l/10>=3){
l = l/10+5;
}
else{
l = (l/10)*10;
}
}

else if(l/10>5)
{
if(l/10>=7){
l = l/10+10;
}
else{
l = (l/10)+5;
}
```